# Custom Fields with empty Values on MS Project

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I am trying to use custom fields to manage a project, but the main task is not showing values for the calculated fields.

I'm working on MS Project and decided to create some Custom Fields. I've created the following tasks:

```
TaskName         StartDate   EndDate   CalculatedStartDate    CalculatedEndDate
 + Main Task     10/8/15      14/8/15 
   - SubTask1    10/8/15      12/8/15    10/8/15               12/8/15
   - SubTask2    13/8/15      14/8/15    13/8/15               14/8/15
```

The *CalculatedStartDate* and the *CalculatedEndDate*, are not showing values for the Main Task.

The calculated fields are formulas. All the formulas I'm using are CustomField=[MS ProjectField]

For Example (Comienzo refers to StartDate. The MS Project Version I'm using is Spanish): 
[image]

Comment: I am voting to close this question as a) it is not clear what is being asked b) the issue has been resolved by the OP and c) the resolution is not clear. Leaving this question (and answer) active may not provide benefit to subsequent site visitors and users.

Answer (score 1):

After writing this question, I realized that I was missing a click on "Cálculo de las filas de asignación>>Usar Fórmula" on the image at the right.

After that, the error was gone.